# Foresight linux repo needs to be rebuild

Tags: linux, repo

We have a serious problem with foresight linux. As we know it, foresight has no support due to the conary package method which is shutdown now. However in our application the build fails because the online repo is not reachable (rpath).

This is the error we get during build:

> Error occurred opening repository http://foresight.rpath.org/conary/: Connection refused

So we found a way to get a list of conary packages on the local server as a dump(from git - mirror of conary repo).

Now we are really not sure on how and where to update foresight Linux to look over new repo path instead of foresight.rpath.org/conary.

The fact is that we would not expect any major upgrade or update on the packages. This is to let build run without getting exit saying online repo issue, so that we can plan and manage until the application gets completely migrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the repo list by yourself, the path is

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess Foresight(conary) does not require sources.list file. I also tried but not able to see /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: is there any other place we could tell foresight linux to look for new repo URL

Comment: do you have any other files on the directory /etc/apy/*.list ?

Comment: <code> $ sudo find / -name  *.list 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/gnome-about/foundation-members.list
/usr/share/gnome-about/contributors.list
/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2/components/components.list
/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2/dependentlibs.list
/usr/lib/firefox-19.0.2/dependentlibs.list </code>

Comment: mmmm... did you try this commands?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine